# How to get data from a json response as a variable

Tags: jmeter, jsonpath

I tried to get the value of a variable named version (first one) using JSONPath but apparently my solution didn't work at all.
I tried to use an expression like $..version or $.container..version .

My response below:

```
{
  "container" : {
    "version" : 8,
    "updatedBy" : "user111",
    "updatedOn" : "2017-08-17T16:00:24Z",
    "id" : 16,
    "dataEnt" : {
      "dataEntid" : "dataEntid-000032",
      "dataEnttype" : "21"
    },
    "impact" : [ ],
    "operationalFocus" : false,
    "periodicity" : {
      "version" : 0,
      "updatedBy" : "unknown",
      "updatedOn" : "2017-03-31T16:44:08Z",
      "step" : 1,
      "period" : 31084132,
      "_VALIDATION" : {
        "valid" : true,
        "saveAll" : true,
        "reasons" : [ ],
        "details" : {
          "period" : {
            "valid" : true,
            "saveAll" : true,
            "risks" : [ ],
            "rmiCode" : null,
            "rmiMessage" : null
          },
          "version" : {
            "valid" : true,
            "saveAll" : true,
            "risks" : [ ],
            "rmiCode" : null,
            "rmiMessage" : null
          },
          "step" : {
            "valid" : true,
            "saveAll" : true,
            "risks" : [ ],
            "rmiCode" : null,
            "rmiMessage" : null
          }
        },
        "rmiCode" : null,
        "rmiMessage" : null
      },
      "_META" : { }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the JSON you pasted is invalid: it's missing 2 curly brackets at the end (root object and `container` objects are not closed). If this is not a copy/paste error on SO, but actual data problem, you may need to correct that first.

If I understood correctly, you want the value from this field in the variable:

```
"version" : 8
```

If so, JSON path should be:

```
$.container.version
```

or

```
container.version
```

if you prefer relative path to absolute.

Path like `$..version` or `$.container..version` will select multiple version fields (`"version" : 0` in `periodicity` property, and the one that is an object inside `_VALIDATION`)

Answer (score 0):

The following expression will get you the desired result.
Variable: **ContainerVersion**
JSON Expression: **$..container.version**
Now the stored version value can be called using: **${ContainerVersion}**

If there are multiple "version" tags are there, then you can load all values of "version" by having following expression,
**$..container.version[*]**
You can call the variable as **${Var_1}**, **${Var_2}** etc..
Add debug sampler to see the loaded variable names and its corresponding values.

Hope the above helps...